# Meteor: Send email if 500 error occurs

Tags: logging, meteor

I'm running some Meteor apps at ec2 and want to be notified by email if a user runs into a 500 error. Is there a way to catch all 500 errors and handle it in one place?

Answer (score 0):

All server-side errors should be getting output into your server log. I run a Meteor app on an EC2 instance that I installed using the script at https://github.com/storyandstructure/meteorite-ec2-install, and it configures things such that my app's logs are saved at `/var/log/myapp.log`; your setup probably has something similar.

As for getting emailed whenever an error occurs, there are two options. For all errors that are thrown as a result of *your* code (i.e. not from a package) just find where you've put the code `throw new Meteor.Error` and add a line `Email.send(...)` right after it. (Of course, make sure you've added the [Email package](http://docs.meteor.com/#email) and set up a valid MAIL_URL.)

You can even catch some errors caused by packages this way, if they return anything back to the calling function; for example the Email package throws an Error if its send() function fails, which you could catch within a `try-catch` block in your code where you're calling `Email.send()` (and then, um, you could call `Email.send` again, which hopefully would work the second time; though if the failure the first time was because of the recipient, maybe an email to *you* instead would do the trick).

For errors that are thrown as a result of packages that don't return any feedback to the calling function, well, that's harder. You'd have to create a separate app, also running daemonized on the server, that read the server log file every so often and looked for `Exception` or `Error:` at the start of a line. Whenever that text was found, your monitoring app would then send you an email (presumably also having copied some recent lines from the log into the body of the email). This other app doesn't need to be a Meteor app, in fact it would probably be better if it were a simple node.js app, not listening on any port. Hopefully the only packages whose errors you're worrying about, like Email, all throw their errors up the chain so that your app logic can catch them and do something about them.

Comment: I don't think this is a valid solution. Ideally you would have a live error tracking solution where your errors are piped to something like Elasticsearch (or email), where you have more control over how you analyze them. Suggesting that this person should either use the `.log` file or manually put `Email.send()` every single time an error is thrown is a decidedly poor mans solution. What if you integrate email notifications into the entire app (which may be quite large) and then suddenly decide that you want to use Raygun or Elasticsearch? You're screwed.

Comment: Instead, there should really be a way in Meteor to intercept all errors thrown on the server (or client) and handle them. I am writing a package right now in Meteor that will override the Meteor.Error method and allow you to inject your own tracking method (without interfering with the rest of its behaviour).

Comment: I'm not sure why my answer justified a downvote, especially since it's been over a year and no one's offered any other suggestions. Certainly there could and should be other solutions, like the package idea suggested in the comments (instructions and/or code, please?) or some way to tell Node itself to send emails when 500 errors fire; and those would probably indeed be better solutions. But the ideas in my answer actually work, and I've actually used them in production on EC2 like the question asked, so they are valid.

Comment: Sure, your solutions technically work, but its really not a proper way to solve the problem.

Comment: Did anyone come up with another solution here?